# How bad is *RECURSION*?

Tags: php, class, recursion

I want to create an `App` object which contains objects for my database, sanitizer, and user. This way, I can simply use a single App object rather than seperately called all of these different objects, as most of my other objects will require most if not all of these objects for the methods within them.

The `User` object will have CRUD methods in the future so that its properties can be changed, therefore, I do not want a separate object from the one which contains the CRUD methods and the one which handles user authentication, signout, etc. The reason being is that I don't want to have the exact same object properties in two separate classes for what is technically the exact same object.

That said, how bad is this recursive occurrence (see how the `App` object is utilized in the `User` class)? Should I bother taking measures to code this differently? Is this a big deal? Keep in mind that this `User` class will be called for CRUD methods, so the user which is signed in will be able to change any other user via this object by simply using a different variable name and instantiating a new instance of it.

```
class App {
    public $db;
    public $sanitizer;
    public $user;
    public $settings;

    function __construct () {
        // create $app->db object
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);      
        $this->db = $db;

        // create $app->sanitizer object
        $this->sanitizer = new Sanitizer();

        // set $app->settings
        $this->setSettings();

        // create $app->user object
        $this->user = new User($this); // NOTE THE RECURSION HERE
        $this->user->setIsSignedIn();

        if ($this->user->is_signed_in) {
            $this->user->populateById();
        }
    }

    function setSettings () {
        $sql = 'select * from `settings`';
        $stm = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stm->execute();
        $res = $stm->fetchAll();

        if ($res) {
            $res = $this->sanitizer->action('sanitize', $res);

            foreach ($res as $r) {
                $this->settings[$r['key']] = $r['value'];
            }
        }
    }
}

class User {
    public $app;
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $token;
    public $is_signed_in = false;

    function __construct ($app) {
        $this->app = $app; // AGAIN, *RECURSION*
    }

    function populateByPost () {        
        foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
            if (property_exists($this, $k)) {
                $this->$k = $v;
            }
        }
    }

    function populateById () {
        $sql = 'select * from `users` where `id`=:id';
        $stm = $this->app->db->prepare($sql);
        $stm->bindParam(':id', $this->id);
        $stm->execute();
        $res = $stm->fetch();

        if ($res) {
            $res = $this->app->sanitizer->action('sanitize', $res);

            foreach ($res as $k => $v) {
                $this->$k = $v;
            }
        }
    }

    function credentialsValid () {
        $sql = 'select * from `users` where `username`=:username';
        $stm = $this->app->db->prepare($sql);
        $stm->bindParam(':username', $this->username);
        $stm->execute();
        $res = $stm->fetch();

        if ($res) {
            if (password_verify($this->password, $res['password'])) {
                $this->id = $res['id'];

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    function createToken () {
        $this->token = password_hash($this->id.'|'.$this->username.'|'.$this->password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $sql = 'insert into `user_tokens` (`id_user`, `token`) values (:id_user, :token)';
        $stm = $this->app->db->prepare($sql);
        $stm->bindParam(':id_user', $this->id);
        $stm->bindParam(':token', $this->token);
        $stm->execute();
    }

    function setSessionVars () {
        $_SESSION['id_user'] = $this->id;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $this->token;

        if (isset($_POST['remember_me'])) {
            setcookie('id_user', $this->id, time() + 31556926, '/');
            setcookie('token', $this->token, time() + 31556926, '/');
        }
    }

    function setIsSignedIn () {
        if (isset($_COOKIE['id_user'])) {
            $id_user = $_COOKIE['id_user'];
            $token = $_COOKIE['token'];
        }
        else if (isset($_SESSION['id_user'])) {
            $id_user = $_SESSION['id_user'];
            $token = $_SESSION['token'];
        }

        if (isset($id_user)) {
            $sql = 'select * from `user_tokens` where `id_user`=:id_user and `token`=:token';
            $stm = $this->app->db->prepare($sql);
            $stm->bindParam(':id_user', $id_user);
            $stm->bindParam(':token', $token);
            $stm->execute();
            $res = $stm->fetch();

            if ($res) {
                $this->id = $res['id_user'];
                $this->is_signed_in = true;
            }
        }
    }

    function signOut () {
        $_SESSION['id_user'] = '';
        $_SESSION['token'] = '';

        session_destroy();

        if (isset($_COOKIE['id_user'])) {
            setcookie('id_user', '', time() - 1, '/');
            setcookie('token', '', time() - 1, '/');
        }
    }

    // CRUD METHODS TO BE ADDED HERE LATER
}
```

Obviously when I print_r the `App` object it tells me there is a recursion within the `App->user` object due to the code in the `App` construct.

Again, I am only curious if this is a really bad thing that I should absolutely recode. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not 'recursion' per se. It could be considered a 'cyclic dependency' as an App "has a user" and a User "knows of the app". If removing the 'user' from the App (what is it doing there?!?) then there is no cyclic dependency at all, and just clean (manual) DI. (Now print_r is it *walks* the dependency graph recursively and it aborts when it finds a loop so it doesn't go on forever.)

Comment: Recursion is when a function or method calls itself, either directly or indirectly through other functions or methods. So what you have is not necessarily recursion but rather interdependency. Dependencies should be minimized and "injected" (dependency injection) where possible. For example, your current `User` methods that need access to database functions could just take a `$db` object when being called, or the sanitizer could be moved outside the class. This way you do not need to depend it on the `App` class. Take a look at how common ORM and MVC frameworks do it.

Comment: How about "mutually recursive"? :) Basically I am just wondering if this is considered bad programming, really. However, I think you answered my question. The user object should probably not be injected inside of another user object.

Comment: Just out of curiosity,  Doesnt ur app object will violate SOC ??

Comment: As I said, recursion is when something applies itself on **itself**, directly or indirectly. Therefore there is no "mutually recursive" by definition. The user object has an indirect reference to itself but does not apply itself. You may have recursion if the same function in an object gets called by itself, but this is not the case here, but rather an app method calling a user method which calls a _different_ app method.